# Partially ordered set- maximum and minimum elements.

Tags: logic, relations

In the set of positive rational numbers, consider partially order relation, defined as follows :
$$\frac{x}{y} \prec \frac{a}{b} \iff \frac{x}{y},\frac{a}{b} \text{are non-reduced fractions}\ \land \ y=b \ \land \frac{x}{y} \le \frac{a}{b}.$$

According to me, fraction that has a numerator equal to zero is minimum element. I also think, that there are no maximum elements, because we can always find larger fraction.

UPDATE:
I came to conclusion, that there are no minimum and maximum elements.

Comment: Positive rational numbers do not contain $\frac{0}{y} = 0$.

Comment: It as infinimum but no minimum if youdont include zero in the positive rational set. What means your $\wedge$ here?

Comment: @EDX All three conditions must be fulfilled.

Comment: @Keba. That's right. So, I think, that we should consider fraction with numerator equal to one.

Comment: @pawelK: Did you really mean **non**-reduced fractions, thereby excluding $\frac12$ and $\frac23$, for instance, or is it supposed to be **reduced** fractions, thereby ruling out $\frac24$ and $\frac46$?